# I can't change PHP session id

Tags: php, session

I am trying to change session id by using

```
session_unset();
```

and

```
session_destroy();
```

after I use `session_start()`.

But I print `session_id()` after each session destroy and it didn't change in all browsers:
IE8, Chrome and Firefox.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: What's the code you're using to print the session_id? Is it being propagated along through the URL?

Comment: Why is the ID of the session relevant?  What trouble is it giving you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `session_regenerate_id` function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php

Comment: Try `Example #1` at this page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php I just did and it works perfectly for me in Chrome, Firefox and IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Try this from the PHP documentation :

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['destroyed'] = time();
session_regenerate_id();
unset($_SESSION['destroyed']);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php